# Can't get a prepared statement to print in php

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to get to grips with `mysqli` but finding it a struggle compared to the now depreciated `mysql`.  So far with the old methods I've been able to get information back about my tables in an associative array.  I'm trying to form a prepared statement and `echo` the `id` number back.  I would also like to be able to print the whole `sql` statement that has been binded, but seen as I can't even echo the `id` number from a single `SELECT` statement, it is out of the question at the moment.

```
$db = new mysqli('xxx', 'xx', 'xx', 'xxxx');

$sql = "SELECT user_id, name FROM users WHERE name=?"

$statement = $db -> prepare($sql);

$statement -> bind_param("s", "Emma");

$statement -> execute();

$statement -> bind_result($id, $name);

$output = $statement -> fetch();

echo $output -> $id . " " . $name;
```

I seem to be getting lost at the line `bind_result`.  I figured if `statement` is an object, then I should be able to `echo` them in the form I have devised?  When I refresh my page I just get nothing. I have 2 entries in my table and 1 of them does have the name string that is used above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You think too complex. Just try this:

```
$db = new mysqli('xxx', 'xx', 'xx', 'xxxx');
$sql = "SELECT user_id, name FROM users WHERE name=?";
$statement = $db->prepare($sql);
$statement->bind_param("s", "Emma");
$statement->execute();
$statement->bind_result($id, $name);
while ($statement->fetch()) {
  echo $id . " " . $name;
}
```

The `bind_result()` methods takes care that for each `$statement->fetch()` you execute you get fresh values in the variables `$id` and `$name`.

You should take a look at the good [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php) of those methods.

Comment: Thanks - so what exactly does `fetch` return?  a boolean?  So `statement->fetch` should always be in a `while` loop?  Its strange seeing variables such as `%id` when they have not been defined in the usual way e.g. `$id = $_GET['id']` or `$id = 5`, etc.

Comment: You comment suggests that you did _not_ take a look at the documentation, since that would have answered your questions right away. May I ask why?

Comment: Sorry, I only seen the link for the docs after I posted my comment.  Been reading them since.

Comment: All fine! Hope I could bring you on the right track. The while loop makes sense because you want to retrieve several separate result elements. Using some sort of loop allows you to handle each element one by one. Good luck!

Comment: Yes, you definitely put me on the right track!  The while loop makes sense now as it appears that in order to increment the pointer that points to each row, a loop is needed.  Thanks again!